# Scanning information to structs through a struct pointer?

Tags: c

In C, say I have:

```
    typedef struct player {
        char Fname[25];
        int Singles;
        int Doubles;
        int Triples;
        int Homeruns;
   } Player;
```

and in main() I defined

```
    Player* players;
```

a pointer to a Player type. Now say I have a function that reads the data for each Player type from a file:

```
    void read_from_file(char* filename, Player* players, int size) {
        FILE* fp;
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        while (players < size) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s%d%d%d%d", *players.Fname, *players.Singles, *players.Doubles, *players.Triples, *players.Homeruns);
            players++;
        }
     }
```

It says that "Fname," "Singles," "Doubles," etc. is requested in something not a struct or a union. But players is being dereferenced, so it should give a struct right? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You did not mention the `stream` in `fscanf` !

Comment: You're right, sorry. That was an error in the question but not in my program. I'm still receiving the same compiler errors

Comment: Have you thought about reading the manual page for `fscanf` and ensure that the parameters are correct. If also my help to check the return value from `fopen`

Comment: What the condition `while (players < size)` is designed to ? Did that mean that `players` has been allocated to an array (`players = malloc(size*sizeof(Player));`) ?

Comment: The relational comparison between a pointer to Player and int makes no sense (and is UB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is operator precedence, since `*players.Fname` actually means `*(players.Fname)` (which does not work as `players` is of type `Player*`), and not `(*players).Fname`, (which would work).

Anyway, you could use operator `->` for accessing members through pointer variables. So you could write ...

```
scanf("%d", &player->Singles);
```

instead of the more clumsy notation ...

```
scanf("%d", &(*player).Singles);
```

Comment: The use of unreferenced form `players->Fname` will be more readable.

Comment: @J. Piquard: just updated my answer in this moment :-)